# Hierarchical Dynamic Listview

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to compose an app for schoolwork scheduling. The main page is a list of courses that the user is studying in the current semester. User can add as many subjects as he or she wishes. When clicking on an item(a course), a pop menu shows up with options such as  "deadlines", "instructors","weblinks","contacts", etc., which are associated with this course.

I created a Mainactivity class and another class called "Deadlines", which handles the "deadlines" option. Mainactivity is configured to point to this "deadlines" class whenever this option is chosen.

However, the problem is that after I add a new item in the deadlines list, click away back to the main page and come back, the items will disappear. This doesn't happen to the mainpage though.

I think maybe I can create an array of instances of the Deadlines class, and add new member to it whenever I add a new item on the main page. However, I don't know how I can achieve that.

I will provide my source code below:
Here is my MainActivity class:

```
package p.listviewexercise3;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static p.listviewexercise3.R.id.deadlines;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText;
    Button button;
    ArrayList list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = editText.getText().toString();
                if (name.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"lol",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    list.add(name);
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
        list = new ArrayList();
        list.add("x");
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long id) {
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, listView);
                popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, popupMenu.getMenu());
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
                        switch(item.getItemId()){
                            case deadlines:
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Deadlines.class);
                                intent.putExtra("ITEM_INDEX", position);
                                startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                popupMenu.show();
            }
        });
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                list.remove(position);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Here's my Deadlines class:

```
package p.listviewexercise3;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by root on 9/28/17.
 */

public class Deadlines extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    EditText editText;
    ListView deadlines;
    ArrayList list;
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.deadlines);
        Intent in = getIntent();
        int index = in.getIntExtra("p.ITEM_INDEX", -1);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        deadlines = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.deadlines);
        list = new ArrayList();
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        deadlines.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String text = editText.getText().toString();
                list.add(text);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```